# Facebook v4 API Permissions

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, permissions

I don't know why but i can't get manage_pages permissions from the new Facebook API (v4) i use this list of scope's (permissions)

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array('public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends' , 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'status_update', 'user_likes',  'photo_upload')) . '">Login</a>';
```

when i login in my app. I just grant the email and public proffile permissions but not other. Any ideas? 
Thanks in advice guys.

Comment: RTM or use the Stackoverflow search function before you post a question: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: The answer why this doesn't work is contained in the link. You cannot use extended permissions if your app isn't reviewed by FB. You can test the app with your admin user.